# Ruby on Rails - database where sorted by id

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have setup the where but attempting to get it to sort by desc. Similar to mysql syntax

> SELECT id, cname, cbn, reason, ticket, note, status, created_at FROM calls WHERE (status='callback' OR status='pending' OR status='open' OR status='NOC Review') AND operator='TWIN' ORDER BY id desc

I currently have this in the controller

```
@cals = Call.where(status: ['open', 'pending', 'Callback'])
```

I attempted the `Call.last(1000), Call.where(status: ['open','pending', 'callback'])`

```
<%  @cals.each do |call| %>
  <tr>
     <th><%= link_to call.id, call_path(call) %></th>
     <th><%= call.cname %></th>
     <th><%= call.cbn %></th>
     <th><%= call.operator  %></th>
     <th><%= call.reason  %></th>
     <th><%= call.ticket %></th>
     <th><%= call.created_at %></th>
     <th><%= call.tier %></th>
     <th><%= call.status %></th>
     <th><%= call.note %></th>
     <th></th>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

When I do the `@cals = Call.last(1000), Call.where(status: ['open', 'pending', 'callback'])` I receive an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
@cals = Call.where(status: ['open', 'pending', 'Callback']).last(1000)
```

or:

```
@cals = Call.where(status: ['open', 'pending', 'Callback']).order('id DESC').limit(1000)
```